# Mapping local folders to Azure DevOps Git Repos in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, version-control, visual-studio-2019

I reinstalled my machine and loaded fresh Visual Studio 2019. I already have local repos on my hard disk and want to re-connect/re-map local repos (root folder) with the existing Azure DevOps remote repos root. Please help.

Here is what I tried so far.

I singed into the Visual Studio using the creds that I use to access remote repos, selected the remote organization node from "Connect to a Project" window. Here the only option I see is "Connect" only.

[image]

When I connected the remote org, the Visual Studio source control setting changed from Git to older TFS and Git menu disappeared.

[image]

I changed the source control setting back to the Git and still not able to find any way to configure/map existing local repos with the remote repositories.

[image]

Comment: The last screenshot is telling you what's going on: You don't have to do anything special. The Git repos already have a remote pointing to Azure DevOps. Just open the project and work normally. Everything's still connected. You might have to re-authenticate, but the Git credential manager will take care of that.

Comment: Amazing. That worked. Please post as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last screenshot is telling you what's going on: You don't have to do anything special. The Git repos already have a remote pointing to Azure DevOps. Just open the project and work normally. Everything's still connected. You might have to re-authenticate, but the Git credential manager will take care of that.