# Git Changes panel in Visual Studio 2022 not showing pull, sync, fetch buttons

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2022

In the fresh install of Visual Studio 2022, the Git Changes panel is not showing all the buttons that we used to use in Visual Studio 2019. I am wondering, how to get back these buttons?

Following is the comparison of Git Changes in VS 2022 and 2019

**VS2019**
[image]

**VS2022**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the git repository don't have remote, only the push button is displayed.

You can add a remote in "Git Changes" by "..." -> "Manage Remotes..." :
[image]

Also, you can use the push button to create a remote repository (GitHub, Azure Repos, ...) and push the local repository.

Comment: I see, but I am confused. Last time when I had reinstalled VS2019, to reconnect my existing local repos to the remote repos I hadn't done this additional step. Refer to my pervious question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600043/mapping-local-folders-to-azure-devops-git-repos-in-visual-studio.

Any explanation what changed and why would be helpful.

Comment: Please note, I have got the new hard drive and installed VS2019 and 2022 both on it. And I am trying to reconnect my local repositories (on my old hard drive which I am using as secondary hard drive) to the remote repositories.

Comment: What show the command `git remote -v` at the repository's root?

Comment: And `git status`?